# Scaling Graphics2D object shifts it

Tags: java, swing

I have a JScrollPane that contains a custom JLabel with an ImageIcon. I want the user to be able to zoom in and out on the image. I'm trying to use the `scale()` method in the Graphics2D class to do it, but whenever I zoom, the image is being shifted down/up and right/left depending on whether I'm zooming in or out. I don't know why this is happening or how to tell how much I need to `translate()` the Graphics2D object to counteract this. I really appreciate any help you guys can give me. Here's my code:

```
class ImageViewer extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private int WIDTH = 800;
    private int HEIGHT = 600;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    JMenuItem zoomIn, zoomOut;
    JPanel panel;
    MyLabel label;

    private String imageUrl = "picture.jpg";
    double scale = 1.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer();
        viewer.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ImageViewer() {
        this.setTitle("Image Viewer");
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        this.setBackground(Color.gray);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(panel);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu zoom = new JMenu("Zoom");
        zoomIn = new JMenuItem("Zoom In");
        zoom.add(zoomIn);
        zoomIn.addActionListener(this);

        zoomOut = new JMenuItem("Zoom Out");
        zoom.add(zoomOut);
        zoomOut.addActionListener(this);

        menubar.add(zoom);
        this.add(menubar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Icon image = new ImageIcon(imageUrl);

        label = new MyLabel(image);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.getViewport().add(label);
        panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object ob = e.getSource();

        if (ob == zoomIn) {
            scale += .1;
            label.revalidate();
            label.repaint();
        }
        if (ob == zoomOut) {
            scale -= .1;
            label.revalidate();
            label.repaint();
        }
    }

    class MyLabel extends JLabel{

        public MyLabel(Icon i){
            super(i);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            AffineTransform at = g2.getTransform();
            g2.scale(scale, scale);
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            super.paintComponent(g2);

            g2.setTransform(at);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            int w = (int)(scale * getIcon().getIconWidth()),
                h = (int)(scale * getIcon().getIconHeight());
            return new Dimension(w, h);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: could it be that your image just has transparent/background color border?

Comment: I thought that jpeg's couldn't have transparency? I've also tried it with other pictures that I know don't have a transparent/grey background and it does the same shifting to them.

Comment: The `scale()` resizes the image, but doesn't change the location where it is drawn. I.E the upper left hand corner stays in the same position regardless of the size of the image. It may appear to be moving, but that is only because of the scaling. Try repainting at a different (x,y)

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't it be "shifting" left and up when zooming in? Right now, when I zoom in it "shifts" right and down. Do you know how I could calculate what x and y I should be repainting at?

Comment: You do realized that the coordinate origin is in the top left corner, right?  So only top left corner should remain stationary when you zoom.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Generate the images in code, or hot-link to [some on the net](http://pscode.org/media/#image).

Comment: @MK I know... The top left corner isn't staying stationary when I zoom.

Comment: @AndrewThompson For the SSCCE, do I have to pack my code into an executable or something? The code I've provided in the OP will run if it is compiled and the imageUrl is changed to point to a local image.

Comment: *"The code I've provided in the OP will run if it is compiled"* There are 42 compilation errors. *"and the imageUrl is changed to point to a local image."*  Why should I have to change anything?  Do you expect 5 people who are helping to change it 5 times?  I would expect they would ignore the question and continue on to one asked by someone who provides code that compiles and runs 'as-is'.  That is the idea of the SSCCE.

Comment: Can't even get close to running your code, so I'll leave this question alone...

Answer (score 4):

Before `g2.scale(scale, scale);` add `g2.translate(desiredX, desiredY);`